# Is it possible to dynamically inject AMP components into an AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to dynamically inject an AMP component into an AMP page?

Ideally, I would like to insert an AMP component (e.g. a widget like `amp-apester-media`) to an AMP page, by using a configuration similar to the one `amp-auto-ads` is using (example taken from [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-auto-ads/?format=websites)):

```
{
  "placements": [
    {
      "anchor": {
        "selector": "DIV#domId",
        "index": 2,
        "sub": {
          "selector": "P.paragraph",
          "all": true
        }
      },
      "pos": 4,
      "type": 1,
      "style": {
        "top_m": 5,
        "bot_m": 10
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there currently a way to achieve this? is it possible to develop an AMP component that would make this possible? thanks everyone.

Comment: many possible interpretations for this question. the quick answer is: use `amp-list` + `amp-mustache`. if you construct your `HTML` and `CSS` effectively, you can combine the two AMP services to solve a wide range of problems. beyond that, you need to show a more specific example, especially one where those services fail to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From what I understand, `amp-mustache`'s "triple-mustache" doesn't support amp components, but only simple tags like `div` and `span`. Also, in my case, I do not control the structure of the page (can only locate something in the header or the beginning of the body) and therefore need some sort of API to inject in different places in the page's body. Another option I looked into is `amp-script`, but it only allows adding elements inside the `amp-script` itself.